Why does SpaceX use a ground crane to assemble launch towers instead of the gin pole method or a tower crane?
Why does SpaceX raise launch tower sections with a ground-based crane instead of the “gin pole” method? TheirLR11350 is a remarkable machine, but can’t the previously assembled tower “bootstrap” the next section, the same way tower cranes assemble skyscrapers?

https://starship-spacex.fandom.com/wiki/LR11350?file=E5O1eRwWYAgpMcR.jpg

https://www.rspoles.com/solutions/products/gin-pole


I like the way tower cranes self-erect, so following this one and +1

I'd guess that it's just simpler to use a readily available non-specialised crane rather than to design or commission a crane for what is essentially a one off building (there will be more than one but each one is likely to be different due to evolutions to the design)

@AlanBirtles .. Good point. But if Starships will eventually be mass produced (and launched) the technique for building launch towers will need to be scaled up. A recent video of the crane with the extension for the top tower section looked scary haywire.

@ErinAnne ... The SpaceX tower is made to be climbed by the chopsticks thingy. You would think it would be easy to design a hydraulic climbing carriage to self-assemble the next tower section.

Yes, it might need to be scaled up in the future, but there's no point working out how to build at scale now when they need to build one every few years, especially when the design might be completely different once they get to that stage
